# Passing value to another class php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Well i have a function called preFinal() that calculate the value form database, and I want to passing the $this->Result of preFinal() to another controller. Cz I need to calculate the $this->Result in B_Class() controller

```
<php?

class A_Class extends CI_Controller {

public $Result;
public function __construct() {

    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('m_hitung');
    $this->models = $this->m_hitung->datasee();
}

public function index () {
    $this->get_data();
    $this->DSR();

}

public function get_data () {

    foreach($this->models as $ambil) {
            $this->get_DSR[] = $ambil->dsrr;
        }

}

public function preFinal() {
    for($i =0; $i < count($this->get_DSR); $i++){
        if ($this->get_DSR[$i] >= 0 && $this->get_DSR[$i] < 40) {
        $this->Result[$i] = 1 * 50;
        }
    }

    return $this->Result;
}

}
?>

//and this is how I made B_class, and I don't know what to code

class B_class extends A_Class {

public function __construct()
{
    parent :: __construct();

}

public function index () {
    print_r($this->preFinal());
}


}
```

well when I try to call the function, it had message about load session failed

Comment: As far as I recall, CI does not support straight-forward passing data between controllers. What you could do is use flashdata to store the data, then load the second controller and after that read the data stored in flashdata. It's quick, simple and relatively painless

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Then you can instasinate your class in your constructor and use the function you want like:

```
$protected $classA;

public function __construct(A_Class  $classA)
{
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->classA = new $classA();
}
```

And inside your function you can do :

```
 print_r($this->classA->preFinal());
```

Another thing is that you can load your controller as a library like :

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/classA');
```

And again in your function access it like we mentioned before

Comment: the error still appear, like "Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php"

Comment: In you class b you should extend the CI_Controller  as well.